# Redux-form can't pass callback to parent after form submisson

Tags: reactjs, callback, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form and it works well but I don't know how to pass a callback to the parent to that state becomes true instead of false so I can show some different content.

Im using this an example https://codesandbox.io/s/0Qzz3843
How would I pass a callback from the submit.js back to the parent component so that it would change a state after a successful form submit?

my submit.js

```
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form'

const baseUrl = process.env.HOST

const submit = body => (
  fetch(`${baseUrl}:9000/new-user`, {
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: body.name,
      email: body.email,
    }),
    method: 'post',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  }).then((response) => {
    response.json()
      .then(data => (
        onSuccess(data);
      ))
  }).catch((error) => {
    throw new SubmissionError({
      _error: error,
    })
  })
)

export default submit
```

Comment: pass a callback to the action, and invoke it after a successful completion of the promise instead.

Comment: try calling another reducer after successful submit that would change your state

Comment: Map a prop from your redux state to your parent component.  On success of the API call, dispatch an action that changes your redux-state variable to true. This will propagate to your parent component and allow you to catch it in WillReceiveNewProps.

Comment: Any code example ?

Comment: It seems to weird that i can't just pass more props to the submit function